# html-style linking in a .css file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

At the moment, all the pages on my site have a line that looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="css/screenpro.css" />
```

screenpro.css is a tiny file that looks like this:

```
@import url("reset.css");
@import url("master.css");
@import url("account.css");
@import url("slideshow.css");
@import url("enriched.css");
@import url("ie.css");
@import url("popup.css");
```

That all works fine. However, I just wrote a little handler that generates a dynamic css file that changes the background colour on the page. I've included it on one of my pages like this:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="ColorChange.ashx" />
```

However, I am very lazy and my site has many pages - I don't want to have to go add this new import on every page. I tried putting this:

```
@import url("../ColorChange.ashx");
```

and this:

```
@import url("ColorChange.ashx");
```

In screenpro.css, but it didn't work. Is there any way for me to include the .ashx page that generates the dynamic css into my existing css tree, or am I going to have to manually link it from every page?

Edit: The interesting bit in ColorChange.ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/css";

    String query = context.Request.UrlReferrer.Query;        
    Match match = Regex.Match(query, "bg=(?<bg>\\w{6})"); 
    if (!match.Success) return;

    context.Response.Write("\n.proaccount div.box, .proouter #pnlHaveResults div.box { background-color:#" + match.Groups[1] + ";}\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that importing all these CSS files is going to be much slower than putting them all in one file, as the browser has to do many requests instead of one. Moreover, @import stops progressive rendering in IE. You can still have the benefit of the structure by writing a small script that puts them all together.

Comment: I shall keep that in mind, thanks. I only recently inherited the codebase for this site from someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sending the proper header? Something like: 'Content-type: text/css'
Because you need it for the browser to identify your response as a CSS.

I haven't use much ASP, but in PHP you can do exactly what you want to do, by just printing first your header, and then your rules.

Comment: The header should be correct. It all works nicely when I have the page with the .ashx file written with <link ... />, just not when I have it imported in the .css file.

Comment: You may use Firefox with Firebug or Chrome with the developer tools to see the response of your scripts calls. Check if it is rendering correctly. Maybe you're missing a semicolon or missing any important character.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an absolute path. If you start all your with a forward slash `/` then this means "from the root of the site". It gives you a solid start point to work from:

```
@import url("/css/ColorChange.ashx");
```

I dont think you also have the content type issue occurring that has been mentioned elsewhere in this thread as you have a line that says:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
```

The only problem with using absolute urls is that sometimes you end up with different dev urls than your live site. For example you might end up with a url like `http://localhost/mysuperapplication/` when you run it in visual studio. There is an easy way to get around this though:

- http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/10/easy-way-to-keep-your-dev-and-live.html

Answer (score 1):

Is the browser caching the old CSS file without the new import line? Try clearing your cache.

Comment: I tried that too, it still doesn't work. This worked out pretty well for me though - I implemented a proper master page for my site, which makes the whole thing so much more maintainable.

Comment: Nice, two birds with one stone :)